# Python - ValueError: unknown url type

Tags: python, iframe, urllib2

I'm trying to extract sources from `<iframes>` attributes like these:

```
   iframes =  [<iframe frameborder="no" height="160px" scrolling="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/308197184%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-VtArH&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true" width="100%"></iframe>, <iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FPauseMusicale&amp;width=300&amp;height=62&amp;show_faces=false&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=false&amp;header=false" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:62px;"></iframe>, <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="169" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLNKCTdT9YSESoQnj5tPP4P9kaIwBCx7F1" width="100%"></iframe>]
```

but when I try to extract it:

```
for iframe in iframes:
    url = urllib2.urlopen(iframe.attrs['src'])
    print (url)
```

I get the following error:

```
   url = urllib2.urlopen(iframe.attrs['src'])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 423, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 285, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: //www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FPauseMusicale&width=300&height=62&show_faces=false&colorscheme=light&stream=false&show_border=false&header=false
```

why am I getting url with no `http` before the `//www`?

Is there some workaround this?

Comment: When websites using SSL certificates (HTTPS), a safe way to remove errors and insecure connections is to do: "//facebook.com" which will take the connection either if it's http or https. Try putting `https:` before the url variable and see if it works like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why am I getting url with no http before the //www

This is a common way to indicate to the user agent that it should use the same scheme (http, https, ftp, file, etc.) as the current page when making a subsequent request. So, for example, if you loaded the current page over https, then those URLs that omit the scheme would be accessed with https.

> Is there some workaround this?

You can use the `urlparse` module to handle this in Python 2 (since that's your version of Python):

```
# from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse    # Python 3
from urlparse import urlparse, urlunparse

for iframe in iframes:
    scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = urlparse(iframe.attrs['src'])
    if not scheme:
        scheme = 'http'    # default scheme you used when getting the current page
    url = urlunparse((scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment))
    print('Fetching {}'.format(url))
    f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
#    print(f.read())    # dumps the response content
```

If you run the above code you should see this output:

```
Fetching https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/308197184%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-VtArH&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&visual=true
Fetching http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FPauseMusicale&width=300&height=62&show_faces=false&colorscheme=light&stream=false&show_border=false&header=false
Fetching http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLNKCTdT9YSESoQnj5tPP4P9kaIwBCx7F1
```

which shows that the default scheme has been applied to the URL.